# How can I fix language of my github repository?

Tags: c++, flutter, dart, github

https://github.com/emreermenek/learning_flutter
I am learning flutter due to that I have a repository called learning_flutter in github which includes an example flutter project but github is showing programing languages incorrectly. How can I fix this?

[image]

I was excepting to see dart language in languages but I saw C++.

Comment: Adding to VonC's answer, flutter engine is written in C/C++. So it is natural to expect those languages to show in language bar. Also, if your flutter project also contains the windows folder then that also will contain C++ files.

Comment: @JustaPerson Good feedback, thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check first the "[`linguist` docs/Troubleshooting](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md)":

> If the language stats bar is reporting a language that you don't expect:
>
> 1. Click on the name of the language in the stats bar to see a list of the files that are identified as that language.
>    Keep in mind this performs a search so the code search restrictions may result in files identified in the language statistics not appearing in the search results.
>    Installing Linguist locally and running it from the command line will give you accurate results.
> 2. If you see files that you didn't write in the search results, consider moving the files into one of the paths for vendored code, or use the manual overrides feature to ignore them.

Note that:

- You can [override the detected languages](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/docs/overrides.md) in a `.gitattributes` file.
- As noted by [Just A Person](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15494398/just-a-person) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75968551/how-can-i-fix-language-of-my-github-repository?noredirect=1#comment133989736_75968551):

  - The Flutter engine is written in C/C++. So it is natural to expect those languages to show in the language bar.
  - Also, if your flutter project also contains the Windows folder then that also will contain C++ files.

Answer (score 0):

We encounter this problem because the `windows`, `macos` and `linux` files in the project files contain c++ code.

To solve this, we need not include `windows`, `macos` and `linux` files when posting the codes on github.